# How to force a rescan in imenu by a function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Obviously, I can type `M-x imenu <RET> * <RET>`; but is there any single function which will force a rescan?  Since I need this for `which-func-mode`, the "auto-rescan" feature is of no use for me; I'd prefer not to have to call `imenu` and then quit immediately, but just call one function (*one function to scan them all?;)*).  A skimming through `imenu.el` didn't help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there's no `imenu-rescan` function.  Looking at the general way the code works, I think it makes sense there's no such function, but there should be a `imenu-flush-cache` function, which is missing.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` requesting such a new feature.  In the mean time, you can `(setq imenu--index-alist nil)` to flush the cache by hand.

Answer (score 4):

This will force an update (the same as if you had clicked the `*Rescan*` item in the menu) after pressing `C-c i`:

```
(global-set-key "\C-ci"
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (imenu--menubar-select imenu--rescan-item)))
```